# Use variable of a included file inside a function

Tags: php, function, variables, include, global

I've got a problem.

I've got 3 files, which'd be:

*apikey.php*

```
<?php

    $apikey = 'xxxxxxxx';

?>
```

*core.php*

```
<?php

    include 'apikey.php';

    /* some other stuff here */

?>
```

*login.php*

```
<?php

    include 'core.php';

    function GetUserData($id) {
        global $apikey;

        /* some other stuff here */

        return $apikey; // <- returning NULL
    }

?>
```

So, as the comment says, $apikey is being returned as NULL.

But using it outside the function GetUserData it works as it should.

Any ideas?

Comment: This should work as intended. Take it step-by-step to verify that $apikey is not overwritten or unset somewhere.

Comment: The code you posted should work without problems....http://codepad.viper-7.com/pNAk6V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to declare the global in `apikey.php` and then define it.

```
global $apikey;
$apikey = 'xxxx';
```

Nevertheless is using a global what you need? 
Think about passing it as a parameter.

Comment: Worked out. But passing as a parameter wouldn't be that good for me, since I'm using this function alot of times in different files.

Answer (score 1):

you need to give the $apikey to the function aswell

```
function GetUserData($id, $apikey) {
```

Comment: Isn't it possible without this? Because I'd like to keep the apikey.php just included once in one file. If you know what I mean.

Comment: I agree with this answer. It is a good alternative to using globals.

Comment: Well you could do it like @noia_0328 but using $_GLOBALS is a bit of a security risk another thing you could do is include the apikey.php directly into the function but you don't want to do this. floube looking at your includes you have core.php included in your login.php and apikey.php included in core.php so you already have apikey.php in your login.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use $GLOBALS variable.

```
<?php
function GetUserData($id) {

    ...        

    return $GLOBALS['apiKey'];
}
?>
```

or you can also define it as constant instead on your apikey.php

```
<?php
define('API_KEY', 'xxxxxx');
?>
```